Formula for First Resolution of Case
I have a formula that calculates the resolution time of Case with the following formula:
(CreatedDate - ClosedDate )*24
I only want this to run when first time when case is resolved (First time the case status changes to Resolved)
Any Hints ?

Formulas are recalculated every time the record is viewed (or queried). So if you want to do a one-time calculation, you need to have additional fields (and something like a flow or a trigger) to store a snapshot of your target data at a specific point in time.

You need to make a new field and stamp it with a flow. Then reference that fiedl in the formula.

You can utilise an IF statement to make sure it only calculates when the Status is the value you want it to be:
IF(ISPICKVAL(Status,"Resolved"),(LastModifiedDate - CreatedDate)*24,null)

It might be better to use a flow to update a number field, as you will be able to add more logic to the flow.
The formula will also run every time the record is updated and the status stays at Resolved. Let's say the status is resolved and then two days later a user updates the record (any field is updated) then the formula will re-calculate which will result in incorrect values for your reporting.
Good luck!
